# Trying to run decompiler in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna, decompiler

I am trying to debug a jar file I don't have source for, in Eclipse Luna

I have tried various decompilers, and can't get things to run.

The most recent seems to be JDEclipse-Realign at http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/

It installs without any trouble. I have set set the default file association for "class without source" to be "Class File Editor" like this

[image]

I added the jar file to be debugged as an external jar to my project.  And when I expand that and right click on a .class file I get what is shown on the web page for JDEclipse-Realign, with Decompiled Source as the default.

[image]

And I am getting the blue and white icons for JDEclipse-Realign when I select a class file.

[image]

But no decompiled source :(  And clicking the blue icon for Attach Decompiled Source does nothing.

I feel like I must be missing one basic thing, but can't figure it out.  No errors, just no source.

Or should I be using a different decompiler?
Are any known to work in Luna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem on Luna and did the following:-

1. Open Eclipse Luna
2. Go to HELP -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. In the find box, type "jad". [stands for Java Decompiler]
4. You will get a single result titles something as "JadClipse for Eclipse ".
5. Click on Install and restart eclipse when prompted. Your issue will be fixed.